# Simple GUI to create xy data and export it to a txt file

Tags: gui

I am looking for a simple GUI tool to create points interactively (Something like Geogebra) using the mouse, then save the points coordinates to a `txt` file as `x, y`.

For example, using the mouse to create the following points:
[image]

Then I would like to export those points to a txt file, like this:
**Example**:

```
0.0 1.2
0.2 3.5
1.2 4.2
7.5 10.8
...
```

I appreciate any recommendation for such a tool (for Windows, Linux, or both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approximately 2 years after I have posted the question, I didn't get any answer. However, I think I have a hacky way to do that.

- Draw a square or a rectangle using the software of your preference. The following is an example of a square:
  [image]
- Import this image to any "**Plot Digitizer**" software, choose the scale of your axes.
- Start clicking inside the square area. The software will register the locations.
- Finally, you can export your data points to a file (e.g: CSV).